# Fancybox - add link of hidden div to caption/title

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, modx-revolution

I use MODx Revo with Fancybox 2 to display images in the Lightbox-view. I have a hidden div for each image, that holds an url with a link.

I want the link to be shown in the Lightbox-View inside the caption/title, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zAe6Z/

So I try to change the "Download"-Link to get changed with the content of the div with the class "bildlink":

```
<a class="album" rel="albumname" href="[[+image]]" title="[[+description]]">
<img src="[[+thumbnail]]" alt="[[+name]]" /></a>

<div style="display:none;" class="bildlink">
[[+url]]
</div>
```

The "variable" [[+url]] holds the url for the link that should get displayed in the Lightbox-view after the description.

I tried this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

bildlink = $('div.bildlink').html();    

$(".album").fancybox({      
    cyclic : 'false',   
        afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = this.title + '<a target="_blank" href="' + bildlink + '">' + bildlink + '</a> ';
    },
    helpers : {
        title   : { type: 'inside' }
    },      
    });         
});
```

By using this script the Link get's changed, but it uses the same link/url of the first item for each item, it's not related to the clicked-element or to the child-div "bildlink" or the clicked-element.

Here's a fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/gEYtB/ (EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/gEYtB/2/)

So how do I get the content of the div "bildlink" of the clicked-element and use this for the link?

Any hints much appreciated!

EDIT: Have been researching and trying a lot, but no luck so far...i thought the "bildlink" must be written new on each click of an element, so i tried to implement it inside the "afterLoad"-function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$(".album").fancybox({      
    cyclic : 'false',   
        afterLoad: function() {
        bildlink = $this.next('div.bildlink').html();
        this.title = this.title + '<a target="_blank" href="' + bildlink + '">' + bildlink + '</a> ';
    },
    helpers : {
        title   : { type: 'inside' }
    },      
    });         
});
```

But this didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable

```
bildlink = $('div.bildlink').html();
```

... will only get the first element with class `bildlink` so this is why. You need to target each `bildlink` selector according to the `index` of the clicked fancybox selector using the `.eq()` method like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".album").fancybox({
        cyclic: 'false',
        afterLoad: function () {
            var bildlink = $('div.bildlink').eq(this.index).html();
            this.title = this.title + ' <a target="_blank" href="' + bildlink + '">' + bildlink + '</a> ';
        },
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        },
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that you still need to re-initialize the variable `bildlink` every time within the callback `afterLoad`, to set the proper `index`.

See forked <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4LLR/)</kbd>

**NOTE** : this solution assumes that all `.bildlink` selectors follow the **same consecutive order** in the DOM as the `.album` selectors